# On what factors does localhost speed depend?

Tags: networking, webserver, speed, localhost, xampp

I am setting up a server in my home. I am using AN1020-21 router for the purpose and my laptop as host. I will use a desktop later if everything goes smooth. I am using XAMPP latest version.

When i visit my local ip via 192.168.1.6, it gives me a download speed of about 40 - 50 mbps, but when I access it from another laptop, it gives a download speed of only 1 mbps. Which is very low, as I will host gatherings of people, who shall connect to the router and access my ip and download content at the same time. Then they will get very less download speed.

Can someone tell me that :

Is my laptop's network card is the problem ?
Is my laptop's processor and ram is the problem ?
Is my router the problem ?
Is my second pc's netword card the problem ?
Or is there any other problem
Also please suggest some ways to speed up the localhost.

Please help me in this issue. Regards Yash

Comment: Sounds like you have 10/100 ports on some hardware and 10/100/1000 on other hardware.  Verify all hardware has the same type of LAN ports.

Comment: Are you saying you get 40 mbps when connecting from a host to itself but much slower speeds from other hosts connecting to it? Are the other systems attempting to connect wirelessly or will these be wired connections? Wired connections on a local network won't use the router to exchange local network traffic.

Comment: "Are you saying you get 40 mbps when connecting from a host to itself but much slower speeds from other hosts connecting to it " Will other computers connected to it will be called as hosts ?

Secondly, the other computers connect througn wifi provided by router